# Find out Average and Percentile from the Histogram

Tags: average

Below is my Histogram information-

> {178=18, 213=1, 114=76, 139=5, 131=10, 176=13, 95=229, 1444=1, 206=5,
>   192=4, 227=2, 185=12, 67=14, 199=4, 148=11, 124=21, 75=226, 1431=1,
>   123=29, 157=16, 96=224, 1422=1, 89=344, 255=1, 266=1, 117=48, 171=14,
>   164=16}

From the above Histogram information, it means-

`18 calls came back in 178 ms`

`1 call came back in 213 ms`

`76 calls came back in 114 ms`

etc etc.

Now I am trying to find out what is the `Average` and what is the `95 percentile` from the above histogram. Meaning on average how much time it is taking and 95% of time, calls came back in how many millseconds?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the histogram, then you can simply reproduce the original data, and compute things the way you 'normally' would.

When you do the 'normal' computation, however, it should inspire ways that you could use the histogram to speed up the calculations....

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean? Can you provide me an example how can i calculate these things from my data?

Comment: what if I cannot reproduce the original data because it's too big? say {1:3.2E7, 2: 4.12E8, 3: 2E5 ...}